# Making a method that will call a second from a qualified name

Tags: java, string, class, reflection, methods

I need a method that will call a second one from a second class. E.g

```
Class commandclass = Class.forName("foo.Class");
Method method = commandclass.getMethod("method", String.class, String.class);
method.invoke(method, "param1", "param2");
```

But I have tried to put this in a method but it is much harder than I thought. I would like it so any public method can be called from any class with any parameters of any type.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  You seem to know that reflection can be used to invoke methods, so what is the specific problem?

Comment: Post example of some class you want to load and describe which method/methods you want to invoke.

Comment: through reflection you can invoke the method so what the problem you are getting

Comment: I need a method that that I can call on different methods

Comment: I need to work on all kinds of methods with or without params of different types

Comment: No problem if you cant help I found it abit tricky to

Comment: @curlip: Define "work on a method".  Without knowing want you want to do in the general case, it's impossible to give any advice.

Comment: Its not posible to give any ideas because the methods will all be vastly different

Comment: If you can't define what it is that you want to do, then how can anybody help?

Comment: I mean I'm asking for a flexible method

Comment: A flexible method that does what??

Comment: Calls the second method with reflection

Comment: You're saying that you want the name of the second method to be passed to the first method as a parameter?  e.g. `void methodInvoker(String name) { ... Method method = clazz.getMethod(name, ...); ... }` What's the problem there?

Comment: No I want to pass the name class its in types of arguments and values for arguments to the first method and have it call the second method whos name was passed with all that infomation

Comment: Well, start writing that method, and when you get stuck on a specific issue, then feel free to post a question ;)

Comment: oh the question is that there could be any amount of args with any type so I dont know how to do that

Comment: You can pass everything as arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass all arguments needed to a method and call your code.

```
// pass "null" for parIdentifiers and parameters if it's a method without any
public static void invokeMethod(String className, String methodName, 
                       Class<?>[] parIdentifiers, Object[] parameters) {
    try {

        // Your code
        Class<?> commandclass = Class.forName(className);
        Method method = commandclass.getMethod(methodName, parIdentifiers);
        method.invoke(method, parameters); 

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | ClassNotFoundException 
           | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException 
           | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class<?>[] types = new Class<?>[]{String.class, String.class};
    Object[] params = new Object[]{"param1", "param2"};
    invokeMethod("foo.Class", "method", types, params);
}
```